# Add Secondary replica set in the same machine?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new at mongodb so this replication is kinda confusing for me. I follow the tutorial [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/). 
I have set up 2 mongod instance in my machine:

```
localhost:27018
localhost:27019
```

with this command:

```
mongod --dbpath /home/db2 --port 27019 --replSet "rs1"
mongod --dbpath /data/db1 --port 27018 --replSet "rs1"
```

When I try to connect and set up replication using this set of command

```
mongo --port 27019
rs1:PRIMARY> rs.add("localhost:27018")
```

It always says:

```
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must
be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2",
"code" : 103
}
```

Any help, please ?

Comment: Mongo is very picky about using *either* "localhost" or "127.0.0.1". So if you specified the address of the instances as "127.0.0.1" you can't add the other replica member by the "localhost" address...

Comment: @Anders Bornholm so what do you think about this ? Is is possible to run several mongo instance on the same machine ? I just want to do this for testing only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better if you choose the machine name (available in terminal right after your username like `user01@10gen.local`) instead of localhost,

Like rs1:PRIMARY> rs.add("10gen.local:27018")

as the best practice always use a logical name to define the replicaset.

Comment: You're right! I just write rs.add('GIGABYTE-PC:27019') in my first mongod instance (27018) and it just works. Thanks

Comment: wait a minute. I just need time to confirm. I just add a data to my PRIMARY instance (27018) and expected it'll be replicated in SECONDARY instance, but instead I got this Error: error: { "$err" : "not master and slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 }

Comment: oh never mind. It's different issue I think. just solved it with rs.slaveOk()