# Configure a Replica Set in local and on a cloud-server

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to configure a Replica Set with 2 members in local e 1 member on a cloud-server.
I started the two instance from local in this way:

```
mongod --port 27117 --dbpath mongodb/rs0-0 --logpath mongodb/rs0-0/mongo.log --replSet rs0 --fork 
mongod --port 27118 --dbpath mongodb/rs0-1 --logpath mongodb/rs0-1/mongo.log --replSet rs0 --fork
```

and then I started the instance on my cloud-server (after opened the port):

```
mongod --port 27119 --dbpath mongoRS/rs0-2 --logpath mongoRS/rs0-2/mongo.log --replSet rs0 --fork
```

So, I started the server to configure the Replica Set:

```
mongo --port 27117

rsconf = {
    _id: "rs0",
    members: [{
        _id: 0,
        host: "localhost:27117"
    }]
}

rs.initiate( rsconf )
rs.add("localhost:27118")
```

Until now all was correct. But when I tryed to add the server-instance a error occurred:

```
rs.add("myServer.it:27119")
```

**"errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must be localhost references, or none must be; found 2 out of 3",**

So I'm thinking that I cannot set this configuration or what?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083292/add-secondary-replica-set-in-the-same-machine Replace your `localhost` reference to your machine name

Answer (score 2):

While trying to add different member in a replSet, you should avoid using localhost(specially when your servers are located at different environments).

Please try below options:

1. Remove existing replSet member: `rs.remove("localhost:27118")`
2. Try to add the server back with host ip(Local Server IP): `rs.add("your_server_IP:27118")`
3. Add the cloud server with Public IP: `rs.add("Cloud_server_public_IP:27119")`

Also ensure 27117,27118 and 27119 ports are opened from both Localhost and Cloud server.

Thanks,

Deep